# Why is my index buffer not being used with glDrawArraysInstanced (OpenGLES 3.0)

Tags: c++, opengl-es, vbo

I can't find much info on this function regarding setup.  I have 2 VBO's.  The first containing position, normal, and color info bound to GL_ARRAY_BUFFER.  The second is the index buffer bound to GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER.  On a non-instanced draw call I am getting the correct models drawn to the screen, but when I do the same call with instanced rendering I get half of the primitives in each instance missing.  I am doing a uniform array filled with translate data indexed by gl_InstanceID.  The translations are working, but half of the primitives are not showing up.  I have ruled out culling as the issue.  I figured that since number of indices passed is required that the draw call would look up the GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER and stride based on the passed in count value.  Could somebody explain to me what is going on behind the scenes?

Comment: Which ES 3.0 implementation are you using?

Comment: I switched to using glDrawElementsInstanced as ratchet freak suggested, and it's now working properly.  Thanks!

Comment: @Cristiano you can show that your question has been answered by clicking on the checkmark on the question that solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because `glDrawArraysInstanced` doesn't use the element buffer but `glDrawElementsInstanced` does

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  How does the hardware know how to draw the faces without an index buffer?

Comment: @Cristiano, it uses data sequentially - each vertex data position corresponds to an index.

Comment: @Cristiano in other words it assumes the index buffer is `[0,1,2,3,4,...]`